# Maven Variables are not replaced into installed pom file

Tags: maven, maven-3

We are using Maven(3.0.3) as build tool and we need to have different version for different environments (DEV , TEST, QA ) . If we pass version property value during build time based on environment , the installed POM doesn't have the passed property values instead it still has the ${app-version}  string.

I saw already there is a bug for this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2971

Is there any other alternative ,because we cannot different POM file for different environments ,which will be hard to maintain..

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: I don't think you're really supposed to use Maven's install mechanism and repositories to create deployment artifacts of your application for various staging environments. A better practice is deploying from a source control tag and doing the build on the target server, or creating a deployment package using the assembly plugin (with configuration files filtered to replace the placeholders there) and distributing that.

Comment: Doing a build on each deployment target, while currently popular in cloud environments is total overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different artifacts for the environments and use the parameter as a classifier. The pom is the same for all three artifacts but the classifier separates them.

Comment: If i have classifier with SNAPSHOT version , does Maven captures timestamp while deploying to remote repository?

Comment: From all I know it should for all artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Maven does not make any variable/property substitution when installing the POM. It is installed as is, that is the principle. You'd better not read any properties from POM (unless this is e.g. version number), bout you should configure your properties in external file (one per stage, e.g. `dev.properties`, `test.properties`, ...) and then configure Maven profiles (again, one per stage) and invoke Maven like `mvn -Pdev` depending on what you want to build. In profile you can package your final application with whatever properties you like (e.g. with the help of [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-resource`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-resource-mojo.html) or [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) + copy rule).

Alternatively you can [filter your resources](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources). For example, you can filter your Spring context XML file, which refers the properties file (so you package all property files, but Spring will refer only some specific). Or you can filter another properties file from which you will learn what is the "main" properties file to use (double indirection).

Answer (score 0):

You should create the archives for your different [targets within a single build](http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/340-Maven-Configuration-For-Multipe-Environments.html) and use as already mentioned the classifier to separate those artifacts from each others.